# Time complexity for a sorted array

Tags: java

Does sorted array equal best case for a sorting algorithm? I don't know for sure.
Let's assume the array is sorted in ascending order.

Also, I'm not entire sure of the reasoning behind the time complexity for these sort algorithms:

- Mergesort on sorted array = `O(nlog2(n))`, can I assume that it doesn't matter if it is sorted or not it will always be O(nlog2(n))?
- Bubble sort on sorted array = `O(n)`, because it just traverses through the array once?
- Quicksort on sorted array = `O(nlog2(n))`? I'm not sure how to explain this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted arrays can equal worst complexity in a few cases.

BubbleSort will give best performance for a sorted array.

HeapSort will give worse performance for a sorted array if you are chaging the sort order ,for ex if you are sorting an array in acesindg order and the inpur array is in descending order

Insertion sort gives great performance on sorted arrays or nearly sorted arrays

Selection sort is O(n^2) irrespective of what array you provide it as an input :)

Regarding your second question, most of the time complexity is always the worst case time complexity. For ex Insertion sort is O(n^2) but works really fast for almost sorted arrays. There are a few sorting algorithms which work great for less than 1000 elements but go into exponential complexity for higher number of elements

Comment: If the array is sorted in ascending order, isn't bubble sort O(n)?

Comment: thanks @user3511965 for cathing typotyped in worst instead of best

Answer (score 1):

An array that is already sorted is often, but not necessarily, the best case for a given sorting algorithm.  For instance, if you choose your pivot point properly, a sorted array could actually be the worst case for quicksort.

Answer (score -1):

Found this answer in the stack, this will explains you better. !!

> It depends upon things like (a) how large the integers are, (b)
>   whether the input array contains integers in a random order or in a
>   nearly-sorted order, (c) whether you need the sorting algorithm to be
>   stable or not, as well as other factors, (d) whether the entire list
>   of numbers fits in memory (in-memory sort vs external sort), and (e)
>   the machine you run it on.
>
> In practice, the sorting algorithm in your language's standard library
>   will probably be pretty good (pretty close to optimal), if you need an
>   in-memory sort. Therefore, in practice, just use whatever sort
>   function is provided by the standard library, and measure running
>   time. Only if you find that (i) sorting is a large fraction of the
>   overall running time, and (ii) the running time is unacceptable,
>   should you bother messing around with the sorting algorithm. If those
>   two conditions do hold, then you can look at the specific aspects of
>   your particular domain and experiment with other fast sorting
>   algorithms.
>
> But realistically, in practice, the sorting algorithm is rarely a
>   major performance bottleneck.

**The complexities of different sort functions can be found at this [link](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)**

*Copied from the [Link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18539)*